# Reset on every navigation controller of my tab bar app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, reset

I have an app which has a tab bar controller with four tabs. Every tab has a navigation controller where you can go deep to a certain number of view controllers.
At a specific time(when I detect there is no connection to the internet) I need to 'reset' every navigation bar, no matter which of them I'm at that moment. 
I have seen answers regarding 'resets' when changing from one tab to another via the tabbar Delegate. But I don´t have such an event ( I need to do it at any random time, when the app goes offline).
I have tried with this method in the app delegate:

```
-(void)resetViews{
    UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    tabController.selectedViewController=[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    UINavigationController *primero=(UINavigationController *)tabController.selectedViewController;
   [primero popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

   ... 
}
```

The code is the same for every tab, that is for index 0,1,2,3. But it doesn´t work. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance,
T.A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)resetViews {
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    for(UIViewController *foo in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
        if([foo isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            UINavigationController *bar = (UINavigationController*)foo;
            [bar popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Untested, but should work.

`tabBarController.viewControllers` is an array of the view controllers that the tab bar controller contains.  Your current code seems to only be resetting the selected tab, right?  This code should reset all of the tabs.

And you don't need to change `tabBarController.selectedViewController` unless mean to change the selected tab.

Comment: Good answer, except I would rename the loop variable, since it's not a view.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just had to make a little adjustment to put it to work: UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        for(UIViewController *foo in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
            if([foo isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
                UINavigationController *controller=(UINavigationController *)foo;
                [controller popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I should add a comment under the accepted reply, but my reputation is too low to do that.

In my case, to grab the viewControllers array, I had to use instead:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.navigationController.parentViewController;
```